# ZXing Autofocus issue

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, autofocus

I write an application for Motorola Xoom tablet with Android 3.1 for my master thesis that can scan multiple QR Codes in real time with it's camera and that displays additional information in the display over recognised QR Codes.

The recognition is done with the ZXing android app (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), I basically just changed the code of the ZXing app so that it can recognise multiple QR Codes at the same time and can do this scan continually, without freezing after a successful scan like the original app does. So my app is basically the ZXing app with continous scanning of multiple QR Codes.

But I'm facing a problem:

1. The ZXing app makes some sort of continous autofocus. It starts the
   autofocus and when it is finished it automatically starts the
   autofocus again. But this method somehow makes the camera brightness
   settings too bright, so that the camera cannot recognize the QR
   Codes because the image is almost totally white. Disabling the autofocus solves the problem, but I need autofocus because otherwise the recognition of the QR Codes is only possible at a certain distance.

   - How can I change the brightness settings of the camera?
   - Does somebody know another possibility for autofocus?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 (Android 4) and I found one solution. I disable autofocus function before I start camera. 1-2 seconds later I enable it. I tried a few approaches and decided to switch autofocus function periodically. To implement this I created util class - FocusHandler.

```
public class FocusHandler implements Runnable{

    private final int FOCUS_OFF_TIME = 2000;
    private final int FOCUS_ON_TIME = 20000;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean state = false;
    private Handler handler;
    private WeakReference<ZXingScannerView> scannerView;

    public FocusHandler(Handler handler, ZXingScannerView scannerView){
        this.handler = handler;
        this.flag = false;
        this.scannerView = new WeakReference<>(scannerView);
    }

    public void start(){
        state = true;
        this.handler.post(this);
    }

    public void stop(){
        state = false;
        scannerView.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!state || this.scannerView.get() == null){
            return;
        }

        int time;
        if (!flag){
            this.scannerView.get().setAutoFocus(flag);
            time = FOCUS_OFF_TIME;
        }
        else{
            this.scannerView.get().setAutoFocus(flag);
            time = FOCUS_ON_TIME;
        }

        flag = !flag;
        handler.postDelayed(this, time);
    }
}
```

/*************** activity ******************/

```
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private FocusHandler focusHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        focusHandler = new FocusHandler(new Handler(), scannerView);
        frameLayout.addView(scannerView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        scannerView.setAutoFocus(false);
        scannerView.startCamera();
        focusHandler.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scannerView.stopCamera();
        focusHandler.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I wonder if it also works on older hardware I had the problem with. Unfortunately I don't have a device at hand to test.

Comment: Great work! This solution works and should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: can it be implemented if I use zxing embedded from here : https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded  ?

Answer (score 3):

I already answered this on the mailing list.

The app can't change the 'quality' of the camera preview: do you mean resolution? resolution is not the limiting factor. Maybe your app is selecting a particularly low resolution; at some point it doesn't help. But scanning 800x600 should be more than enough for QR codes.

Auto-focus is unrelated to brightness. The camera driver itself is always automatically adjusting exposure. The app does not control this, and can't; the best you can do is modify the exposure setting in later versions of the Android API.

Comment: The one you just posted to! https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zxing/0Q-OB1dYIIY/K3a2FmnB6JgJ

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the answer! You pointed me into the right direction. The exposure is the problem. Normally the camera has auto-exposure, but during autofocus, the auto-exposure is stopped. And as my app always directly restarts the autofocus when it has finished, auto-exposure never works. I have to figure out how I can solve this problem. Maybe waiting a moment between auto-focus cycles.

Source where I found that auto-exposure stops during autofocus:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)

Comment: Interesting I had not seen this behavior on my devices so it is apparently optional. Yes I guess you need to pause between focusings.

Comment: Ah, link is missing a parenthesis. Here's the correct link: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback))

Comment: "But auto-focus routine may stop auto-exposure and auto-white balance transiently during focusing. " in Android Camera SDK, under public final void autoFocus.
I have exactly the same problem like dude: I'm using an autofocus method based on accelerometer readings, so continuous focus is also my goal. This results on exposure issues: picture either stays blackish or whitish, and it hardly gets back to normal. 
Sometimes shaking the device seems to help getting things back to normal.
Sometimes the issues happens, sometimes not.
It seems to be more visible on Galaxy Tab 10.1.
This issue is Weird.

Comment: This "answer" doesn't help solving the issue described in the question, it is merely a general presentation of some details related to the topic. Please change it to comment.

Comment: Same issue for me on a Samsung Galaxy Tab, were you able to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems on some devices (for me it also happened on a Android 3.0 device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1), after a successful autofocus call, the auto exposure remains locked. Doing another focus towards a different luminosity area, the auto exposure will engage again, but remain locked after focus is complete. not yet sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Enable isContinuousFocusEnabled.

```
barcodeScannerView.barcodeView.cameraSettings.isContinuousFocusEnabled = true
```